# Profile is listing 199 reputation, /reputation lists 200

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

On the 28th November I had a total of 32 upvotes and gave one downvote. This should mean that my reputation is capped at 200, however my profile lists this as 199:

[image: Example]

My [/reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) page correctly lists this as 200, *however* that doesn't appear to include the downvote at all:

[image: Example 2]

Comment: was the post you downvoted on 11/28 deleted (returning your -1 to you) or did you undo that downvote on a later date?

Comment: @psubsee2003 nope. But 32 upvotes and 1 downvote should equal a total of 319 reputation, not 199. The reputation from upvotes is capped at 200, however as far as I'm aware receiving 21 upvotes should give me back the reputation from that 1 downvote.

Comment: This is actually strange. Now it looks like that the last event you did was downvote, however timestamps show it wasn't. Check "show removed posts".

Comment: @psubsee2003: yeah, missed the time stamps, removed that comment.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly The reputation tab on your profile is only a rough approximation based on when reputation events happened.  The `/reputation` page is more exact.  Why I asked about the post you downvoted getting deleted is the the deletion technically causes the reputation loss never to have happened in the first place, so the -1 never existed in your true reputation calculation.

Comment: Related: [Separate and visually indicate reversed events from the day's reputation changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146682/separate-and-visually-indicate-reversed-events-from-the-days-reputation-changes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You downvoted a post that was later deleted.

Your reputation log still reflects that you downvoted, but a *later day* will have a `+1 post removed` entry.

The entry is only there to mark *when you voted and would have lost reputation*; the actual vote is undone as the post is now deleted. As such it doesn't play in the cap for that day either, the vote did not need to be compensated for by an otherwise capped upvote.

Your reputation audit trail doesn't include deleted posts, so the `-1` downvote isn't listed there.

Comment: Shouldn't it still be showing 200 instead of 199 though, as I received more than 200 reputation-worth of upvotes, or is the 200 a '*once it hits 200 it stops counting upvotes altogether*'?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: no, because the `-1` is not compensated anymore on that day. The vote is undone (as the post was deleted), it is only there to mark when you downvoted.